# Can an element be a quadratic residue and a generator (mod p)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

i.e. is is possible for

- $g$ to be a generator$\mod{p}$, and
- $g \equiv x^2 \mod{p}$ for some $x$

I'm guessing not, as I think $x$ can't be expressed as a power of $g$, contradicting g being a generator?

Comment: Dear malikyo_o: Your argument is almost complete! You should try harder!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $p$ is an odd prime, then no. $\varphi(p)=p-1$ is even and the multiplicative group $\!\!\!\pmod{p}$ has order $\varphi(p)$.  If $g=x^2$, then $g^{(p-1)/2}=x^{p-1}=1\pmod{p}$. But if $g$ is a generator of the multiplicative group $\!\!\!\pmod{p}$, $g^k\not=1\pmod{p}$ for $0<k<p-1$.

In fact, the only $p$ for which $\varphi(p)$ is odd is $p=2$, and $1=1^2$ is a generator for the multiplicative group $\!\!\!\pmod{2}$.  For all other $p$, $g=x^2$ cannot be a generator of the multiplicative group $\!\!\!\pmod{p}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider $p=2$ to be a prime number (and I wouldn't know how you could defend not doing so) then you will see that $1$ is both a quadratic residue and a generator mod $2$ (admittedly not very spectacular, but true nontheless). This is the only case, as explained the answer by robjohn.

Comment: I have added that $p$ is an odd prime in the first paragraph. Thanks for keeping me on my toes.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late :) but another way to see that this cannot be true for $p>2$ is using the following theorem:

> For a prime $p>2$, exactly half of the elements in $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$ are QRs.

If the generator is a QR, then so is every other element.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you so much!! This is extremely helpful. I have now copied everything and have also verified that the links work and are safely bookmarked. Thanks again - I really appreciate all of your help! Have a great day :)